# How can i store in a MySQL Database, a Table that holds for each table in my database its daily size, extracted from information_schema?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I've created a Table called `analytics_daily_table_sizes` with four columns: date, table_schema, table_name, size_mb.

This table holds for each Table in my Database, its size in MB, updated on a daily basis.

To do this, I created a scheduled event that looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myUser` EVENT `daily_fill_table_space` 
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2021-10-22 03:00:00' 
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE DISABLE 
    ON SLAVE COMMENT 'Creates for each table a new row on a daily basis with that table size in MB' 
        DO 
            Insert into `analytics_daily_table_sizes` 
                    (`date`, table_schema, `table_name`, size_mb)
                SELECT curdate() - Interval 1 day, 
                        TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, 
                        round((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024, 2)
                FROM information_schema.TABLES
                WHERE TABLE_TYPE != 'VIEW' 
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA IN('schema1', 'schema2')
```

I've read in the MySQL documentation that columns from information_schema that represent stats hold cached values and the system variable that defines its expiry is information_schema_stats_expiry, which for is 24 hours (default).

The problem i'm facing is that when evaluating the evolution, only a few tables change its size through the days (the minority). I know for a fact that many of my tables (the larger ones which interest me the most), grow significantly on a daily basis.

I even tested this, executing a select statement before my event ran on a specific table getting the real size, but when checking after the event completed, the table had the same constant value.

- Does anyone know how can I get this to work?
- Why do a few tables update while the others stay the same since the start of the event?

Comment: I do not think that this will work. DATA_LENGTH is the size of the file containing the data, not of the data stored. It might be that the MySQL engine pre-allocates more file space than absolutely necessary. Also check the UPDATE_TIME column which tells when a table last has been changed (does not work for all table types).

Comment: Are all your tables innodb? The cached stats would behave differently on MyISAM tables or any other storage engine.

Comment: @lukas.j is correct that InnoDB pre-allocates space. Tablespaces are sized in "extents" which is 1MB worth of pages. Tables grow in increments, so the data within the extents might not add up to the total physical file size (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_autoextend_increment)

Comment: Hello, thank for your responses, my tables are InnoDB.

Also, the size of the file is exactly what i want!

Lastly, i was aware of the pre allocation and i discarded this because manually querying information schema for DATA_LENGTH, for one of my biggest tables, i got one number. Later, after my event had run, the number for that table was the same as the last few days, which was smaller than the number i got manually querying.

For this to be explained by pre allocation i understand that the number i got when manually querying should have been smaller than the one from my event right?